# How to create a UIScrollView in storyboard?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview, uibutton, storyboard

Using storyboard I created a  `UIScrollView`  and added a `UIImage` to `UIScrollview` and Now I want to add 10 buttons in inside a `UIScrollView`. How to scroll the buttons and the image in the `UIScrollView`.?

I tried but it did not work properly.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

At the end, when you implemented all stuff to the view, make an outlet for the UIScrollview and simply go to the viewcontroller.m file and put in some code to make the scrollview scroll. Atfer this step this should work. If not, make sure that `Autolayout` is disabled.

Here my tutorial for you:

1.Implement a scrollview

[image]

Put in a Image View, if you like.

[image]

set up the image size and file.

[image]

go to your .h file and add an scrollview outlet.

[image]

switch to .m file and put this code in the `viewDidLoad` medthod and replace the size to your contentSize which you desire. For example the width (x) = 320 and the high (y) = 700.

[image]

then simply connect the outlet to the scrollview itself:

[image]

and maybe change some details:

[image]

Thats all, hope it worked.

Best regards

Comment: HI I just followed your way . But I didn't get . I'm using it in the UISplitViewController . Do I need to change anything>?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.  The thing that 'fixed' it is **disabling autolayout**, as @MasterRazer mentioned above.
I still need to figure out what constraints I should use if I want to use autolayout, shouldn't bee too hard though.

**update:** It looks like it's harder than I thought to get the UIScrollView working with Autolayout, look at this page for more information: [iOS6 Release Notes](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/RN-iOSSDK-6_0/index.html) Search for *Here are some notes regarding Auto Layout support for UIScrollView*

Answer (score 0):

In the Document Outline to the left in storyboards drag all your items (buttons, and images) into the scroll view and place it inside the scroll views hierarchy. Looks something like this:
[image]

Comment: It's wise to add a single container UIView to the scrollview. Then add buttons and images to the container. Its helps movement, clipping and setContentSize.